# goormIDE / ERROR: npm v10.2.5 is known not to run on Node.js v14.21.3. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I'm using goormIDE as it's one of course requirements I'm attending to.

I created a file.js and I need to install mysql package; when I type 'npm install mysql' into terminal I get below error message. How can I update node version being in goormide and finally install mysql package?

```
root@goorm:/workspace/Node# npm install mysql
ERROR: npm v10.2.5 is known not to run on Node.js v14.21.3.  This version of npm supports the     following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the la
test version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/agents.js:105
    options.lookup ??= this.#options.lookup
                   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
```